# How is the management external to the Scrum Team involved in the Daily Scrum?

Tags: scrum, daily-scrum, scrum-team

I had a question during PSM1 assessment:

> How is the management external to the Scrum Team involved in the Daily Scrum?

- The Scrum Master speaks on their behalf
- Management gives an update at the start of each daily scrum.
- The development team self-manages and is the - only management required at the Daily scrum.
- The product owner represents their opinions.

Can anyone suggest me proper answer out of given options?

My choice is: `The development team self-manages and is the - only management required at the Daily scrum` - As per my knowledge Daily Scrum is belongs to development team only and they are responsible and accountable. But not sure I'm correct.

Comment: Which do you think is the answer, and why?

Comment: @ToddA.Jacobs - `The development team self-manages and is the - only management required at the Daily scrum` - As per my knowledge Daily Scrum is belongs to development team only and they are responsible and accountable. But not sure I'm correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct. The Daily Scrum is a meeting for the development team to coordinate the work they will be doing in that day (or more accurately, in the time till the next Daily Scrum).

People outside the team (including those in a management role) are allowed to be present in the Daily Scrum, but they are not allowed to interfere or speak up.

Answer (score 3):

Answer to your question is:

> The development team self-manages and is the - only management required at the Daily scrum

*The Daily Scrum is an internal meeting for the Development Team. If others are present, the Scrum Master ensures that they do not disrupt the meeting.*

Only development team member is allowed to speak/present concern of other members, in the Daily Scrum.

Here is reference: [ScrumGuide.org](https://www.scrumguides.org/scrum-guide.html#events-daily)

Answer (score 1):

I'm preparing PSM1, and on my way I found the same question (*How is management external to the Scrum Team involved in the Daily Scrum?*) in a training exam where i had to select the correct ones (as you can see in the attatched image) and, in the end (once submited the my answers), there was an explanation provided by the people behind the exam.

The correct one's were

- The Development Team self-manages and is the only management required at the Daily Scrum. All others cannot attend.
- Management gives an update at the start of each Daily Scrum.

The explanation reads

> The Daily Scrum is a 15-minute time-boxed event for the Development Team. The Daily Scrum is an internal meeting for the Development Team. If others are present, the Scrum Master ensures that they do not disrupt the meeting. So it's better management not to attend.

[image: How is management external to the Scrum Team involved in the Daily Scrum]

Comment: I think this is incorrect. In the explanation it even says its better for management not to attend. This is not a helpful answer.

Comment: Be careful of such test sites. They feature outdated and often wrong answers, that have been long revisted by the official testers. It is a hard test, study hard. Good luck!